# Remove a href if the same one has been already scraped

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website and I don't want to print two same href but only one. I can't figure out, could someone give me an intuition to follow ?

```
url = "http://www.fveconstruction.ch/anMetier.asp?M=04&R=4&PageSize=1000&BoolsMember=0"
get_url = requests.get(url)
get_text = get_url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('anDetails.asp')):
    href = link.get('href')
    #If statement ?
        
    print(href)
```

For example here, if a run the code, I'm going to have each href link doubled. Is there a if statement to remove and keep one of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `set` on the `find_all` but you'd still most likely have duplicates since the object could differ but still contain the same href.

In which case you just create a list and append each href to the list.

Then you could create an if condition to check if it is already in the list before printing it out.

So you'd have

```
href_list = []
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('anDetails.asp')):

    href = link.get('href')
    if href not in href_list:
        print(href)
        href_list.append(href)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any conditional statement to do this. All you need is use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) buit-in to remove duplicates from the result.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, "html.parser")
links = {link['href'] for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('anDetails.asp'))} 
print(links)
```

Comment: @J.jaques it doesn't just work. This is how you should do it.